# Use desktop as hard drive enclosure

Tags: external-hard-drive

My aging desktop's motherboard sometimes doesn't boot up. I think one of the hard drives where the OS is is dying...

I have 6 other drives hooked up to the motherboard. I was thinking about buying just hard drive enclosure like [this from amazon](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131631)

But O wanted to see if there is a way to use my existing desktop as disk enclosure. I would like to connect my laptop USB3 to the desktop or eSata or something...

I bought a new laptop recently so not looking to invest in this old desktop anymore unless it is less than $100.

My desktop does turn on, just that Windows doesn't boot up properly and I am too lazy to do the Windows repair :)

My motherboard: [asus](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131631)

Comment: A motherboard cannot be used without a processor running the OS, so the answer is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly doable, if all what you want is "drive enclosure". Desktop, when powered up, will supply power to the drive(s) and then you can plug it/them into your laptop. That way desktop will serve as a power supply only. If you want to plug in more than one, you need to have port multiplier along the way:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-To-5-SATA-2-0-Port-Multiplier-Card-3Gbps-SATAII-Riser-card-/191584861854

[SATA External Cable Shielded eSATA to SATA (Type “I”) to (Type “L”)](http://www.satacables.com/html/esata-external-esata-shielded-.html)

Same goes for SATA-USB adapter. You would need to invest in something like:

[SATA to USB adapter](http://www.legitreviews.com/vantec-sata-ide-to-usb-3-adapter-review_131412)

My advice is to invest in at least 1m long cables (however check requirements for port multiplier to work properly), as it will be LOUD (compared to a laptop, of course). I wouldn't want to sit next to that stuff especially when case will be opened somewhere (just a crack, yes, but still...). Put it into a cabinet somewhere or something...

There are "but"s, however... First - it needs to power up properly. If you say it's the windows installer that's broken - fine, it won't matter. But if you cannibalize it for parts, it may not work - as other answers point out, cpu, for example, is needed for board to POST. Without it, or other critical parts - nada.

Second has to do with multiplier - most of them are 3GB/s only. Admittedly - not a problem when compared to USB 2.0, but 3.0 will be faster. Also, I don't remember exactly how the multiplier uses bandwith...

**EDIT** - Also, I'm not sure port multiplier will work with USB. It is an adapter, not simple cable, yes, but port multiplication is part of the SATA specification You may be limited to e-SATA after all. And in that case there possibly can be an hot-swap issue. Again: hot-swap is SATA specification, but how that will work with multiplier nobody knows. At least nobody I know I know knows...

Comment: Kudos for being the only answer that actually gets the point. However I would point out you do *not* need a working CPU or any other critical parts to supply power to drives and a port multiplier. The only critical part you need to supply power, is a power supply. Most power supplies can be powered up without anything else connected.

Comment: Most power supplies wont power up without working motherboard connected to working power switch.... And while most boards power up peripherals (like drives) with system power-on, only after passing POST power's being kept supplied. Successfully passing POST, I might add. Yes, not always. But you need to be at least after chipset/cpu check phase, since failing that one will cause MB to cut power to everything except beeper and maybe some diagnostic LEDs. If failing other stages of POST occurs it starts timer after which system's being powered down automatically...

Comment: Most power supplies *will* power up without anything connected.  If it doesn't power on, it violates the ATX standard and is faulty. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PS-ON+ATX

Comment: No. Case in point: if you want to power up ATX power supply alone you need to short pin PS_ON with ground. This is the function of the power button in the case, which - If I may point out - is connected to MB, not to PSU. You can power it up, but ATX specs says PS_ON is MB controlled.

Comment: Ermm, so you're arguing, having to *turn it on yourself* means a power supply will not turn on without a motherboard *and* CPU? That's the most absurd rubbish I've heard all week. The ATX spec says nothing about PS_ON being MB controlled, it simply says the PSU has to turn ON when the signal is asserted. You're quite obviously wrong. Learn to deal with it.

Comment: Correct. Now, then - how to send the PS_ON signal when all you have is PSU? Only way I know is to short PS_ON with GND, which, incidentally, is what pressing PWR button in computer casing does. How you see it done? I'm not arguing it the only way. I'm arguing it's the only way I know to do it normally.

Comment: As clearly described in the link I posted earlier, you can connect the PWR-ON pin by hand. Or, buy one of these: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bitspower-BP-WTP-J02-Pin-Always-connector/dp/B001CXNQL4/ref=sr_1_16?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1435148395&sr=1-16&keywords=ATX+power+on

And this is most certainly *not* what pressing the PWR button in a computer case does. There is *no* direct connection between the power button and the PS-ON signal pins - the signal pin is directly controlled by a logic chip, which is in has the power button as one of it's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the desktop as an external hard disk because it can't act as a USB slave and I've never heard a solution for that. However you can share the files over LAN easily, or install a NAS server on it to make it more functional.

If Windows can't boot you can use a bootable Linux USB to boot it and share. You can also install Linux, which is lighter and easier for server purposes.

Comment: what's wrong with this?